# Is it possible to search for a rendition of an image based on the dimensions via QueryBuilder API

Tags: aem, assets, query-builder, dam

What I would like to achieve is the following. Based on the specified dimension and an asset title I would like to find all the asset renditions which correspond to the search criteria.

Currently, I am using the QueryBuilder API as I am not working in Java but it seems impossible that in just one call to the AEM I manage to get the wanted rendition.

What would be the best way for searching the image renditions?

Looking forward to your ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You can do with SQL2 JOIN query:

```
SELECT parent.* FROM [dam:AssetContent] AS parent INNER JOIN [nt:file] AS child ON ISDESCENDANTNODE(child,parent) WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(parent, '/content/dam') AND parent.[cq:name]='men_5.jpg' and name(child)='cq5dam.thumbnail.48.48.png'
```

`parent` looks for dam:AssetContent nodes with name=men_5.jpg and `child` looks for nt:file nodes under corresponding asset with nodename=cq5dam.thumbnail.48.48.png

Comment: Thank you for the response! Could you tell me as well is it possible to run this query via an HTTP API?

Comment: 2 options: 1) run the query from crxde->tools->query; from network tab, you can pull query.jsp call. It returns json as expected. But this works only from author. 
2) Using sling servlet to run query and return results -https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/using-query-builder-servlet.html

Comment: Can sling servlets be used from languages other than Java?

Comment: Oh I understood. You dont want to write java servlet. You are right to use QueryBuilder API and hit using curl; example: curl -s -u admin:admin GET "http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?path=%2fcontent%dam%2fen&property=fileReference&property.value=%2fcontent%2fdam%2fgeometrixx%2fshapes%2ftri_equilateral.png&type=nt%3aunstructured". Issue is, it runs only XPath Queries. You ll need to run 2 Xpath queries and merge results at your end OR try some XPath Join queries. I am not sure how to join 2 xpath queries.